# How to use moment.js to get remaining hours, minutes, and seconds from a unix timestamp?

Tags: javascript, momentjs, moment-timezone

Given a unix timstamp in the future, how can I use Moment.js to get the hours, minutes, and seconds remaining until then?

For example:

```
now  = 1589252712837
time = 1589356202907

// This is the line I do not know
res = moment(time - now)

console.log(res)
// 23 hours, 12 minutes, 3 seconds
```

Edit:

I believe I can do something like this, but is there a native way to do it?:

```
now  = 1589252712837
time = 1589356202907
remaining = time - now

hour = moment(remaining).hour()
minute = moment(remaining).minute()
second = moment(remaining).second()

console.log(`${hour} hours, `${minute} minutes, ${seconds} seconds`)
// 23 hours, 12 minutes, 3 seconds
```

Comment: format('HH:mm:ss')

Comment: And is there either a "human readable" or "23 hours, 12 minutes, 3 seconds" way of  doing it?

Comment: well, there's the twitter style humanize(),  Also there's moment.duration() that can wrap up the remaining value

Comment: hacky way to do it by extracting from _data: ```Object.entries(moment.duration(remaining,'milliseconds')._data).reverse().map(([unit,value])=>value!==0?`${value} ${unit}`:'').join(' ')```

Comment: note that the times are wrong in your examples, you have to use moment.utc if you want to use the other methods that don't convert to duration.  do remaining/1000/3600 to see that it's actually 28 hours.  You may want to look at https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the example code you have is being time offset: `remaining/1000/60/60`~=28, not 23.  You need to use `moment.utc`.  I don't recommend doing that though, because you'll encounter other problems like dealing with days and months.

As far as "native" support, see long discussion here: https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/463
TL;DR: Discussed from 2012 until now.  And, in the docs they point at the [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) plugin.
Look at this plugin if you want something close to "native" support:
https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format

Honestly after looking at the situation, if it were me I'd probably just use [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format), or just use `humanize()`.  Maybe roll my own similar to how duration._data is generated + Intl.NumberFormat, which is what I'm guessing [moment-duration-format](https://github.com/jsmreese/moment-duration-format) is basically already doing.

I'm going to list some possible methods as far as I can see:

```js
now  = 1589252712837
time = 1589356202907
remaining = time - now

// extract key(units),value from parsed ._data property of duration
// no additional dependencies but depends on internal private variable _data
console.log(
Object.entries(moment.duration(remaining,'milliseconds')._data).reverse()
  .flatMap(([unit,value])=>value!==0?`${value} ${unit}`:[]).join(' ')
);

// using moment-duration-format plugin
console.log(moment.duration(remaining,'milliseconds').format('h [hours] m [minutes] s [seconds]'))

// twitter style humanize
console.log(moment.duration(remaining,'milliseconds').humanize());

// hours threshhold is Infinity; never round up to higher units than hours
console.log(moment.duration(remaining,'milliseconds').humanize({h:Infinity}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.25.3/moment.min.js"></script>

<!-- moment-duration-format plugin -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/2.3.1/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Pass option `{trim: false}` to `.format('date format string', {trim: false})` to keep it from "trimming" off 0 values (eg: if hours was 0 it would try to "trim" off the hours portion)