# seconds to "DD:HH:mm:ss" with moment()

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs

I am trying to convert seconds to `DD:HH:mm:ss` format or other formats like (`YYYYMMDD`)

```js
function secToFormat(seconds, format){
  return moment.utc(seconds * 1000).format(format);
}

// works well.
console.log(secToFormat(40,"HH:mm:ss"));
console.log(secToFormat(100,"HH:mm:ss"));
console.log(secToFormat(1800,"HH:mm:ss"));
console.log(secToFormat(18800,"HH:mm:ss"));
console.log(secToFormat(86300,"HH:mm:ss"));

// doesn't work I expected.
console.log(secToFormat(40,"DD:HH:mm:ss"));  //it returns 01:00:00:40 but I expect 00:00:00:40
console.log(secToFormat(100,"DD:HH:mm:ss"));  //it returns 01:00:01:40 but I expect 00:00:01:40
console.log(secToFormat(86300,"DD:HH:mm:ss"));  //it returns 01:23:58:20 but I expect 00:23:58:20
console.log(secToFormat(86400*2,"DD:HH:mm:ss"));  //it returns 03:00:00:00 but I expect 02:00:00:00

// it also doesn't work with another format.
console.log(secToFormat(40, "MM:DD:HH:mm:ss")); // I want to get 00:00:00:00:40
console.log(secToFormat(100, "MM:DD:HH:mm:ss")); // I want to get 00:00:00:01:40
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

I understand why it happens because it starts at `1970-01-01 00:00:00`.

but I want to edit it what I expect.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: _"I am trying to convert seconds"_  _seconds_ from **when**? Why would `DD` ever result in a value of `00`? There is no 0th day of the month

Comment: @Phil it depends on the input.

Comment: @Phil okay, Imagine you are making a `countdown`. If you input `86400` seconds and it should be `01:00:00:00`,  not `02:00:00:00`.

Comment: In that case, you want [Durations](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/)

Comment: Would you fix my code using Duration? I am not used to Duration.

Comment: the D token in moment.js is the [day of the month](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) (typically called the date). Why not just write your own function? It's pretty simple if you assume exactly 24 hrs per day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use moment.js' [durations](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/), however they don't have much in the way of formatting, e.g.

```js
let seconds = 28763827;
let duration = moment.duration(seconds, 'seconds');
console.log('Default ISO: ' + duration); // "PT7989H57M7S"
console.log('Moment humanized: ' + duration.humanize()); // a year
console.log('Moment days: ' + duration.asDays()); // 332.91466435185185
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Consider writing your own function to convert to a format like d.HH:mm:ss, e.g.

```js
function secsToTime(secs) {
  let d = secs / 8.64e4 | 0;
  let H = (secs % 8.64e4) / 3.6e3 | 0;
  let m = (secs % 3.6e3)  / 60 | 0;
  let s = secs % 60;
  let z = n=> (n < 10? '0' : '') + n;
  return `${d}.${z(H)}:${z(m)}:${z(s)}`
}

let seconds = 28763827;
console.log(secsToTime(seconds));
```

Comment: @user120242—post it as an answer or mark this as a duplicate.

Comment: I just want to note that the `moment-duration-format` plugin is actually the "officially referenced" way (by momentjs author in issues) to format, and you don't need to roll your own.  I've created several ways to do formatting in this answer as well as explanation for "what's the hold up in putting this into momentjs directly" here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61743114/how-to-use-moment-js-to-get-remaining-hours-minutes-and-seconds-from-a-unix-ti/61744139#61744139

Comment: I was searching for this for 3 days . Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Using `moment-duration-format` to implement.
It is actually the "officially referenced" way (by momentjs author in both issues and docs).  Explanation and examples here in my other answer:
[How to use moment.js to get remaining hours, minutes, and seconds from a unix timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61743114/how-to-use-moment-js-to-get-remaining-hours-minutes-and-seconds-from-a-unix-ti/61744139#61744139)

@RobG's answer is a great base for rolling your own, and I am tempted to edit it into my answer in above link.  But note that `moment-duration-format` already exists and is the sanctioned way to do it, as well as being an actively updated library, and really satisfies most any use case I can think of (eg: drop-in one statement replacement in OP's example code).

It is also possible to extract the data directly from duration's internal variable `_data`.  Though, I really don't recommend doing that.  I have a rough demo of that in the other answer.

```js
function secToFormat(seconds, format){
  return moment.duration(seconds,'seconds').format(format, {trim: false});
  // trim: false so it doesn't trim off 0 values
  // (so last one would be 01:40 instead of 00:00:00:01:40 if trim: true)
}

// works well.
console.log(secToFormat(40,"HH:mm:ss"));
console.log(secToFormat(100,"HH:mm:ss"));
console.log(secToFormat(1800,"HH:mm:ss"));
console.log(secToFormat(18800,"HH:mm:ss"));
console.log(secToFormat(86300,"HH:mm:ss"));

// doesn't work I expected.
console.log(secToFormat(40,"DD:HH:mm:ss"));  //it returns 01:00:00:40 but I expect 00:00:00:40
console.log(secToFormat(100,"DD:HH:mm:ss"));  //it returns 01:00:01:40 but I expect 00:00:01:40
console.log(secToFormat(86300,"DD:HH:mm:ss"));  //it returns 01:23:58:20 but I expect 00:23:58:20
console.log(secToFormat(86400*2,"DD:HH:mm:ss"));  //it returns 03:00:00:00 but I expect 02:00:00:00

// it also doesn't work with another format.
console.log(secToFormat(40, "MM:DD:HH:mm:ss")); // I want to get 00:00:00:00:40
console.log(secToFormat(100, "MM:DD:HH:mm:ss")); // I want to get 00:00:00:01:40
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.26.0/moment.min.js"></script>

<!-- moment-duration-format plugin -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment-duration-format/2.3.1/moment-duration-format.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That line in the secToFormat code is giving the error ```Property 'format' does not exist on type 'Duration'. ```